# How to retrieve data from firebase by using listview in react native

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am trying to build an app with group-chat feature by using react-native now.

There are two pages here, one is use to store info of new groups (such as group name and group profile), the other page is for list down all the groups already stored into firebase database.

Now I am able to store those data into database, but listview is empty in this moment.

{rowData.text.groupName}

This is the way I am fetching my data. The 'groupName' is my column name.

Comment: did you see this demo - https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/the-beginners-guide-to-react-native-and_84.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, this problem already solved.

Comment: [This tutorial](http://bitvbit.blogspot.com/2016/08/react-native-firebase-tutorial-list.html) that I wrote may be helpful for anyone interested in making a list view with React-Native/Firebase in Android. It was inspired by the iOS one that Aaron had shared.